# uitableview reload problem

Tags: iphone, scroll, reload, tableview

i have a tableviewcontroller and inside it i am trying loading data of the table. i have an array and creating my custom table cells using this array. it works fine at first time but when i want to refresh table data (after updating array i call reloadData method of tableview) but updated data appears after scrolling. and also new array size is shorter than the first one it throws exception when scrolling toward bottoms.

reloadData does not work properly

```
myArray = [self getNewData:0];  //updating array which is used to creating cells
[self.tableView reloadData];    //reload data
```

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the call to reloadData is being completely uneffective. So check that `self.tableView` is non-nil at the point you're calling it -- put an NSLog above that line like so:

```
NSLog(@" self.tableView = %@", self.tableView);
```

If it's nil, that's your problem.

Comment: self.tableView = (null)
you are right. but how could it be null, i am shocked.

Comment: no i do not use IB. inside loadview method i create it like below and never release it. 
 self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 370) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

Comment: So where in your code are you doing the call to reloadData? Show us the full method, or better describe it. If self.tableView = nil, then either it's not been set up yet at the point you do reloadData, or something has nilled it off.

Comment: i have a very strange situation. if i add my table into a uiview it is set nil else not.  the code causes problem
[mainView addSubview:self.tableView];
[self reloadPage:1 firstCase:YES];
self.view = mainView;

Comment: if i use like below it doest not set nil
[self reloadPage:1 firstCase:YES];
self.view = self.tableView;

Answer (score 1):

You said, updated Data is appearing after scrolling. 
Are you adding labels in your cell and not removing them? remove all the labels added on your cell before customizing it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    for (UIView * view in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;
    }
    //Your customization
    return cell;
}
```

This might be the case.
But what [occulus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348476/occulus) suggested seems to be more precise solution to me.